# Is there a way in AWS to hide my nodejs code while expose access and storage related billing information to my customers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I am in a situation where I need to do some calculations based upon data provided by the customer, store the result somewhere, and make the result available through APIs. For this, I have produced a NodeJS app that can store the data in a NoSQL DB.

My issue is that I want the customer to pay for everything without seeing the source-code. I dont need to make any money for myself, just allow the customer to pay the bills without seeing my calculations.

For this, I am considering AWS. I can spin out an EC2 instance, run my NodeJS code on it and store all the data in RDS, S3, etc. I have two possibilities from this point:

1. I pay for the AWS account (ie, put my Credit Card Details), and recover the bill from the customer; or
2. I ask the customer to create an AWS account, give me some sort of access so that I can download my code on EC2 etc

For option 1, the question is

> Is there a way in AWS (IAM user etc) such that a customer can login to
>   the AWS console, view the billing and usage information, but *cannot*
>   logon to EC2 and see the Node source code

For option 2,

> Is it even possible that the owner of the account doesnt get to see
>   the source-code on their EC2 instance

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Amazon has a tutorial on exactly that:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html

I would suggest starting there and then asking additional questions here, and we can try and help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in AWS (IAM user etc) such that a customer can login to
>   the AWS console, view the billing and usage information, but cannot
>   logon to EC2 and see the Node source code

This seems like a fit for [AWS marketplace AMI based product](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/ami-products.html) offering. You can offer your AMI on the marketplace for your customers. Your customers would need an AWS account to buy your AMI and they will be charged by AWS on your behalf. You will be paid by AWS.

> Is it even possible that the owner of the account doesn't get to see
>   the source-code on their EC2 instance

I believe one of the ways to do this to disable the sshd process on the AMI that you create. There can be better alternatives to this but I just put what I could guess.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to totally protect something from the owner of an AWS Account.

To give an example, think of the pre-cloud world. If somebody has **physical access** to a computer, they could open the case and **remove the hard disk**. By attaching the disk to another computer, they could read the contents. But, you might say, what if the contents is password-protected? Yes, that would help, but how does the app access the contents without knowing the password?

Exactly the same thing applies in the cloud. If you are using an Amazon EC2 instance, then **the disk can be copied via a Snapshot** and attached to another computer. The contents can be read.

You might be **super-smart** and know how to make an EC2 instance with an encrypted volume that can boot and serve traffic, without giving people permission to login. If they attach the disk to another EC2 instance, it should be unreadable because the boot volume is encrypted. (But then how does it work when booted?)

If you want to be totally sure about protecting your code, I would recommend:

- Use **your own AWS Account** (so they don't have access)
- Setup **Consolidated Billing** (so they get the bill, but they don't have access to the account)
- **Provide an API** that they can call (either via API Gateway + Lambda, or an Amazon EC2 instance). You can even get fancy and use [AWS PrivateLink - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud Connectivity Options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-vpc-connectivity-options/aws-privatelink.html), which exposes a service in another AWS Account without traversing the Internet.

The result is that only **you have total access to the resources, but they pay for the account**. This would only work if you have a *single* customer using the service, since the whole cost of that account will go to them. (It wouldn't be appropriate if you are servicing multiple customers from the same account.)